# C# Console Black Jack

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, инспекция-кода

Всем хай ,прогаю на c# 3 месяца ,сделал блек джек в консоли, можете оценить код и сказать какие у меня там ошибки, где можно сделать более красиво или эффективно.Помогите улучшить свой говнокод))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _21
{
    public class Deck
    {
        protected List<string> deck = new List<string>{"2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9", "9", "j", "j", "j", "j", "q", "q", "q", "q", "k", "k", "k", "k", "a", "a", "a", "a"};
        protected string GiveCard()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int cardindex = rnd.Next(0, deck.Count);
            string card =  deck[cardindex];
            deck.RemoveAt(cardindex);
            return card;

        }
    }
    public class Player: Deck
    {
        private List<string> playershand = new List<string>();
        private int playershandprice;
        private int balance = 1000;
        private int playersbet;
        public void Bet(int bet)
        {
            balance -= bet;
            playersbet = bet;
        }
        public int GetPlayersBet()
        {
            return playersbet;
        }
        public void GivePrize(int prize)
        {
            balance += prize;
        }
        public void  Hand()
        {
            playershand.Add(GiveCard());
            playershand.Add(GiveCard());
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                int cardprice;
                if(int.TryParse(playershand[i], out cardprice))
                {
                    playershandprice += cardprice;     
                }
                else
                {
                    if(playershand[i]!="a")
                    {
                        playershandprice += 10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(playershandprice == 11)
                        {
                            playershandprice = 2;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            playershandprice += 11;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void ShowPlaersHandPrice()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(playershandprice);
        }
        public void AddCard()
        {
            playershand.Add(GiveCard());
            int cardprice;
            if (int.TryParse(playershand[playershand.Count-1], out cardprice))
            {
                playershandprice += cardprice;
            }
            else
            {
                if (playershand[playershand.Count - 1] != "a")
                {
                    playershandprice += 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    playershandprice += 11;
                }
            }
        }
        public int GetPlaersHandPrice()
        {
            return playershandprice;
        }
        public int GetPlayersBalance()
        {
            return balance;
        }

    }

    public class Dealer: Deck
    {
        private string[] dealershand = {"",""};
        private int dealershandprice;
        private int dealersfirstcard;
        public void Hand()
        {
            dealershand[0] = GiveCard();
            dealershand[1] = GiveCard();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                int cardprice;
                if (int.TryParse(dealershand[i], out cardprice))
                {
                    dealershandprice += cardprice;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (dealershand[i] != "a")
                    {
                        dealershandprice += 10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (dealershandprice == 11)
                        {
                            dealershandprice = 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dealershandprice += 11;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    dealersfirstcard = cardprice;
                }
            }
        }
        public void ShowDealersFirstCard()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dealersfirstcard);
        }
        public void ShowDealersHandPrice()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dealershandprice);
        }
        public int GetDealersHandPrice()
        {
            return dealershandprice;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string flag = "";
            while(flag!="end")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать в блек джек");
                Console.WriteLine("Введите start ,чтобы начать играть");
                flag = Console.ReadLine();
                if(flag == "start")
                {
                    Deck deck = new Deck();
                    Player player= new Player();
                    Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
                    Console.Write("Ваш баланс:");
                    Console.WriteLine(player.GetPlayersBalance());
                    Console.Write("введите вашу ставку:");
                    player.Bet(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                    player.Hand();
                    Console.Write("Ваша рука:");
                    player.ShowPlaersHandPrice();
                    dealer.Hand();
                    Console.Write("1 карта дилера:");
                    dealer.ShowDealersFirstCard();
                    string flag1 = "";
                    while(flag1!="no")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите yes , если xотите добрать карту, и no ,если не хотите");
                        flag1 = Console.ReadLine();
                        if(flag1 =="yes")
                        {
                            player.AddCard();
                            Console.Write("Ваша рука:");
                            player.ShowPlaersHandPrice();
                        }
                    }
                    if(player.GetPlaersHandPrice() > 21)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ваша рука:");
                        player.ShowPlaersHandPrice();
                        Console.Write("Рука дилера:");
                        dealer.ShowDealersHandPrice();
                        Console.WriteLine("Вы проиграли,ваша рука больше 21");

                    }
                    else if(player.GetPlaersHandPrice() < dealer.GetDealersHandPrice())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ваша рука:");
                        player.ShowPlaersHandPrice();
                        Console.Write("Рука дилера:");
                        dealer.ShowDealersHandPrice();
                        Console.WriteLine("Вы проиграли,рука дилера больше");
                    }
                    else if(player.GetPlaersHandPrice() > dealer.GetDealersHandPrice())
                    {
                        if(player.GetPlaersHandPrice()!=21)
                            player.GivePrize(player.GetPlayersBet()*2);
                        else
                            player.GivePrize(player.GetPlayersBet() * 3);
                        Console.WriteLine("Ваша рука:");
                        player.ShowPlaersHandPrice();
                        Console.Write("Рука дилера:");
                        dealer.ShowDealersHandPrice();
                        Console.WriteLine("Вы Выиграли");
                        Console.Write("Ваш баланс:");
                        Console.WriteLine(player.GetPlayersBalance());
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        player.GivePrize(player.GetPlayersBet());
                        Console.WriteLine("Ваша рука:");
                        player.ShowPlaersHandPrice();
                        Console.Write("Рука дилера:");
                        dealer.ShowDealersHandPrice();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ничья");
                        Console.Write("Ваш баланс:");
                        Console.WriteLine(player.GetPlayersBalance());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = "end";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что конкретно оценить то? вы какие то приемы тут использовали? ООП? Паттерны? Алгоритм какой? Я вижу пару тяп ляп слепленных классов, но не вижу ничего, что бы тут оценивать. Я могу по коду пройтись и рассказать, что у вас хорошо, а что плохо, если это то, что вы ищите, но хотелось бы от вас услышать что конкретно из своих знаний по прошраммированию вы использовали, чтобы написать код, что написали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Много `if-else`.
2. Дублируете код.
3. `string flag` плохо, используйте специально созданный для этого `enum`.
4. Ошибка в игре, где у игрока и дилера своя колода карт.
5. Есть проблемы с именованием, а именно `dealershandprice`, принято писать `dealersHandPrice`, каждое слово с большой буквы.
6. `if (dealershand[i] != "a")` - наверно стоит сделать отдельный класс, который будет содержать в себе информацию о карте?
7. Наследуете `Player` от `Deck`, это если бы вы наследовали машину от карандаша. Игрок не может быть колодой карт.
8. `player.Bet(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));` - а если напишу `wqeqe`?
9. Можно брать бесконечное число карт, даже если у игрока уже выше 21.
10. После игры нужно повторно писать `start`, зачем тогда баланс, если он сбивается?

Это, пожалуй, минимум, который я нашел, мельком проверив ваш код. Давайте теперь попробуем сделать более-менее приемлемо.

1. Создадим новый класс, назовем его `Card`, пусть отвечает за одну конкретную карту (тут играйтесь как хотите, я для примера добавлю название):

   ```
    public class Card
    {
        public Card(string name, int value, CardType type)
            => (Name, Value, Type) = (name, value, type);

        public string Name { get; init; }
        public int Value { get; init; }
        public CardType Type { get; init; }
    }
   ```

   Тип тут является простым `enum`:

   ```
    public enum CardType
    {
        Number,
        Jack,
        Queen,
        King,
        Ace
    }
   ```
2. Создадим теперь колоду карт (класс `Deck`):

   ```
    public class Deck
    {
        private readonly List<Card> cards = new();
        public Deck() => GenerateCards();

        public Card Take()
        {
            if (IsEmpty) return null;
            var card = cards[new Random().Next(cards.Count)];
            cards.Remove(card);

            return card;
        }

        public bool IsEmpty => !cards.Any();
        public int Count => cards.Count;

        private void GenerateCards()
        {
            foreach (var type in Enum.GetValues<CardType>())
            {
                if (type is CardType.Number)
                {
                    for (int i = 2; i <= 9; i++)
                    {
                        cards.AddRange(CreateCardsByType(type, i));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cards.AddRange(CreateCardsByType(type));
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<Card> CreateCardsByType(CardType type, int value = 0)
        {
            List<Card> result = new();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Card card = type switch
                {
                    CardType.Number => new($"{value}", value, type),
                    CardType.Jack => new($"Валет", 10, type),
                    CardType.Queen => new($"Дама", 10, type),
                    CardType.King => new($"Король", 10, type),
                    CardType.Ace => new($"Туз", 11, type),
                };

                result.Add(card);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
   ```

   Здесь я заменил ваш статичный набор на простую генерацию.

   - `List<Card> cards` - набор наших карт.
   - `public Deck() => GenerateCards();` - вызываем генерацию при инициализации класса.
   - `Card Take()` - Взять (если есть) карту и удалить ее из колоды.
   - `bool IsEmpty` - Проверяем, есть ли еще карта. `.Any()` - это LINQ, можно заменить на нечто простое, по типу `cards.Count == 0` (`cards is { Count: 0 }`).
   - `int Count` - коллекция карт наружу не отдается, а число карт может и понадобиться.
   - `void GenerateCards()` - Генерируем колоду карт.
   - `IEnumerable<Card> CreateCardsByType(...)` - Создаем 4 карты одного типа.
3. Создаем игрока (класс `Player`):

   ```
    public class Player
    {
        private Deck deck;
        private List<Card> cards = new();

        public Player(string name, Deck deck) 
            => (Name, this.deck) = (name, deck);

        public string Name { get; init; }
        public int Money { get; private set; } = 1000;
        public int Score { get; private set; }
        public int Cards => cards.Count;
        public bool IsLost => Score > 21;

        public bool Take()
        {
            if (IsLost) return false;
            var card = deck.Take();
            cards.Add(card);
            Score += card.Value;
            return !IsLost;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Score = 0;
            cards.Clear();
        }
    }
   ```

   Я не стал тут реализовывать функционал денег, думаю справитесь сами, задача была просто и наглядно показать, как стоит поступить, а конкретно то, что в классе есть только необходимый для игрока функционал.
4. Так, колода карт есть, игрок есть, дилер, по сути, тоже есть (ведь это тоже в некотором роде игрок, верно?), осталось наклепать класс игры (`Game`):

   ```
    public class Game
    {
        private Deck deck = new();
        private Player[] players;

        public Game()
        {
            players = new[]
            {
                new Player("Дилер", deck),
                new Player("Игрок", deck)
            };

            Start();
        }

        public bool IsEnded { get; private set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            bool replay = true;
            while (replay)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Turn();
                IsEnded = players.Any(x => x.IsLost);

                Console.ReadLine();

                if (IsEnded)
                    replay = Replay();
            }
        }

        private void Turn()
        {
            foreach (var player in players)
            {
                var status = player.Take() ? "Еще в игре" : "Проиграл";
                Console.WriteLine($"У {player.Name} {player.Score}, он {status}");
            }
        }

        private bool Replay()
        {
            bool result = false;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Повторить? (y/n): ");
                var value = Console.ReadLine();

                if (value is "y" or "n")
                {
                    result = value is "y";
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (result)
            {
                Reset();
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void Reset()
        {
            deck = new();
            foreach (var player in players)
            {
                player.Reset();
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   Опять же, я многое не сделал, лишь показал каркас того, как стоило бы поступить.  Этот класс будет поочередно брать карту у каждого игрока из массива, а когда один из них зайдет за пределы, игра завершится и предложит нам переиграть.

Этим ответом я не пытаюсь решить ваши косяки (о которых написал выше), моя задача показать вам как в языке C# используются базовые принципы ООП, а именно, создаются отдельные объекты, со своей логикой и значениями, как они друг с другом взаимодействуют. Старайтесь следовать этим правилам, а также правилам SOLID, это очень сильно облегчит вам жизнь!

Из того, что нужно доделать (домашнее задание?):

- Реализовать валюту игрока (ее трату и пополнение, а также запоминание, чтобы каждая игра начиналась со старым балансом.).
- Реализовать логику туза, ведь эта карта может дать как 1, так и 11.
- Реализовать запрос "взять еще карту?".
- Реализовать завершение игры, если закончились карты.
- Постараться вынести все взаимодействие с консолью в отдельный класс.

В общем, удачи вам в изучении C#!

Comment: Я бы еще для каждого типа карты отдельный класс написал, а `Card` сделал бы интерфейсом. Все же вряд ли нужно позволять создавать карту, например, "семерку", с Value == 2.

Comment: @Andrei, слишком много одинаковых классов получается, лучше уж тогда сделать приватный конструктор и метод для получения целой колоды или отдельной карты по нужде